# Error commonly occurs when code is incompatible

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a VBA module within an excel document I am working on. I got everything working on my laptop and finally published it to my team to begin a wave of testing.

Unfortunately, a lot of them are met with the following error:

> Compile error in hidden module: pushEmail. This error commonly occurs when code is incompatible with the version, platform, or architecture of this application.

At first, I assumed that people were not using the same version of Excel as I was (Excel 2016), however, it turns out that they all were. Other solutions I've attempted are:

- Checking the references to ensure that all were included on other user's computers. They were.
- Check the add-ins I was using on excel. Besides the default ones, I had none.
- Ensure I was using 32/64bit compatible code (as per a recommended solution I found through google). Me and my team all have x64 computers.

I'm not sure what else to try and I have been through the first 30 pages of Google to try and find a solution, to no avail. Could someone suggest a solution that I could attempt?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**
Here is the code in question:

```
 Sub AcceptPush()
    Dim track As Excel.Workbook
    Dim push As Excel.Workbook
    Dim trackFC As Excel.Workbook
    Dim trackWks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim pushWks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim FCWks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim pName As String
    Dim TLPass As Variant
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim rngFoundCell As Range
    Set rng = Nothing
    Dim MyCell As Range


    Set push = Workbooks("Push Alert - Software.xlsm")
    Set pushWks = push.Worksheets("Push")
    Set rngFoundCell = pushWks.Range("R11:R53").Find(What:="y")

    pName = pushWks.Range("D2").Value

    TLPass = InputBox("Enter the TL Password")

    Select Case TLPass
        Case "password"
            MsgBox "Password correct"
            If rngFoundCell Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "You did not select a push to accept."
            Else
                Set track = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Account Pushing Tracker - Software.xlsm")
                Set trackWks = track.Worksheets("Accounts")
                Set trackFC = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Account Pushing Tracker - Team Tax.xlsm")
                Set FCWks = trackFC.Worksheets("Accounts")
                pushWks.Range("PushData[#All]").AdvancedFilter _
                Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
                CriteriaRange:=push.Worksheets("Filter Criteria").Range("B6:Q7")
                pushWks.Range("R:S").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                pushWks.Range("PushData").Copy
                trackWks.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues
                pushWks.Range("PushData").Copy
                FCWks.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues
                pushWks.Range("R:S").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                pushWks.Range("PushData").ClearContents
                pushWks.ShowAllData
                Range("A1").Select
                Application.CutCopyMode = True
                track.Close SaveChanges:=True
                trackFC.Close SaveChanges:=True
            End If
        Case Else
            MsgBox "INCORRECT! Your attempt has been recorded"
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").Unprotect "123"
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Application.UserName
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").Protect "123"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Post the code that is causing the problem. You say your team all have x64 computers, but do they all have the same (32 or 64 bit) version of Excel installed?

Comment: What happens when someone tries to compile the code explicitly? Like go to the ribbon and select `Debug>Compile`? Which line of code is highlighted?

Comment: Try moving the code via Notepad from your workbook to a new one created on a target computer.

Comment: @Olly - I just checked and everyone is running the same version.

Comment: What references do you have checked in that workbook?

Answer (score 0):

When I try to compile your code, it shows you haven't declared the `Rng` variable:

```
Set Rng = Nothing
```

Comment: I never received this error. How odd. I've removed this line and any references of this line but I'm still getting the above error.

Comment: When you debug > compile, which line is highlighted as causing the problem?

Comment: The following line is causing the error. > Dim olApp As Outlook.Application. It is not a reference issue as everyone who is using it has the library necessary to function.

Comment: @OliverWilliams I don't see that line, `Dim olApp As Outlook.Application` anywhere in the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

this can occure if 2 Installation of Word/Excel (64 /32 ) or rest of them are on computer.
The apdada....\Excel\STARTUP must be empty too
Maybe try to deinstall all Excel entirely and after new installation try again